# how to find via style in selenium

Tags: selenium

I have the following html code:

```
<tr id="d20209567" style="display: table-row;"><td class="f">7</td><td    class="bc">20209567</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="s"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="sb('20209567');">SEÇ</a></td></tr>
```

I want to find that tag via a find_element_by_xpath. How do I incorporate style in the following call?

```
find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='bfiltresp']//tbody//tr"
```

Something like the following didnt work

```
find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='bfiltresp']//tbody//tr[@style='display: table-row']"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following worked

```
contains(@style,'display: table-row;')
```

the final call would be:

```
find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='bfiltresp']//tbody//tr[contains(@style,'display: table-row;')]")
```